# import both python 2 and 3 modules in a single python file for conditional execution

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, function, import

I am trying to conditionally execute two python scripts in a single python script like so.

```
# main.py
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] > 2:
    from scripts.script3 import script3
    script3()
else:
    from scripts.script2 import script2
    script2()
```

This version works with a Python3 interpreter but if I switch to Python 2 it breaks. For Python2 I created a work around using an `__init__.py` in the scripts folder but when I switched back to Python3 it broke that version.

main.py 
/scripts/ 
├── script2.py (Python2) 
└── script3.py (Python3)

Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the following directory layout, I think I accomplished what you want to do:

```
.
├── app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── a.py
└── scripts
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── b.py
    └── c.py
```

```
% python3 -m app.a
Hello, Python 3!
% python -m app.a
Good day, Python 2.
```

`app/a.py` looks like this:

```
import sys

if sys.version_info[0] > 2:
    from scripts.b import fun
else:
    from scripts.c import fun

fun()
```

**Edit**: if you want to go full minimal, the following appears to work as well:

```
.
├── a.py
└── scripts
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── b.py
    └── c.py
```

Then you can just run `a.py` with `python a.py` (or `python3 a.py`).

Comment: Are both of your init files empty? I am getting No module named 'scripts'

Comment: It works for me if I don't create the app directory and leave the scripts `__init__.py` empty. Thanks for your help